# A finite poset $P$ is inductive iff it has a least element

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

The question (in the title) is from *Notes on Set Theory* by Moschovakis, 2nd edition chapter 6.

First, I am not exactly sure what they mean by "it has a least element." I guessed that the author means that "iff it has a subset $S$ such that $S$ has a least element and that no element of $S$ is comparable to any other element outside of it." But then, the set containing $a,b,c$ and with its nontrivial relations as only $a \leq b$ and $c \leq b$ is inductive, but it doesn't have a least element according to this interpretation... So I am forced to assume that the author means that "iff it has a subset $S$ such that $S$ has a least element." (this is my interpretation for the rest of this post.) But then, *any* nonempty $P$ has a least element if we take this interpretation, since given $a \in P$, $a$ is a least element of $\{ a \}$ so that we are required to prove that *every* finite poset is inductive...

Assuming the second interpretation:
I tried induction on the number of elements $n$ of $P = \{x_1,...,x_n \}$. For $n=1$ the statement is true trivially. Assume the result for $k <n$.

Let $S$ be a chain in $P$. If $S \neq P$ then by induction $S$ has a supremum. If $S=P$ then $S':=S - \{ x_n \{$ has a supremum, say $x_1$. Since $S=P$ is a chain, either $x_1 \leq x_n$ or $x_n \ x_1$, and the greater of the two is a shpremum.

Is this solution correct?

Edit: For clarification, the author uses the definition that a poset is inductive iff every chain has a least upper bound; in a chain, every element in a chain is comparable.

Comment: (P,<=) has a least element when exists a in P with for all x in P, a <= x.

Comment: I don't understand, every nonempty finite poset is inductive : take a chain, either it's empty in which case any element of $P$ will do, or it's not, in which case it's a finite totally ordered set, hence has a maximum, hence an upper bound

Comment: @Max.  What definition of inductive set are you using?

Comment: @WilliamElliot the one from Zorn's lemma : a poset is inductive iff any chain has an upper bound

Comment: Then @Max every finite order is inductive.  What definition does Moschovakis use?

Comment: @Max: That definition would make $\mathbb N$ with the usual order non-inductive (but $\mathbb N$ with the reverse order _would_ be inductive) which sounds quite strange. The first few references for Zorn's lemma I checked also don't use the word "inductive" about the chains-have-upper-bounds criterion. Where have you found this usage?

Comment: Hmm, I do see "inductive" in that sense used by M. Artin's _Algebra_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : it may also be a mistake on my part; in French it is definitely the usage of the word "inductif" (see for instance the French wikipedia page "Ensemble inductif"); I may not have been careful enough when translating it. (according to wikipedia about "Inductive set", this is also how Bourbaki defines an inductive set, but then again it's in french)

Comment: I'm going to guess that the definition of "inductive" that is intended in the question is "every chain has a least upper bound". Then finiteness ensures that this holds for every nonempty chain (since such a chain has a top element), and the additional assumption that the poset has a least element is exactly what's needed to take care of the empty chain.